# MySQL WHERE Array

Tags: php, mysql

I have been reading through, testing, and coming up short from understanding how to create a MySQL statement that matches a column against an array of values...

Here's what I have...

```
<form id="form" action="index.php" method="post">
<?
$query = "SELECT Interest FROM Interests";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="Interest[]" value="' . $row['Interest'] . '" /> ' . $row['Interest'] . '<br />';
}
?>
<input id="Search" name="Search" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<?
if (isset($_POST['Search']))
{
    $InterestMatches = implode(',', $_POST['Interest']);
    $query = "SELECT MemberID FROM MemberInterests WHERE Interest IN ( $InterestMatches )";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if (!$result) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
        die($message);
    }
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $ResultingMemberIDs[] += $row['MemberID'];
    }
}
?>
```

And what I always get is the same error...

```
Unknown column 'WhateverInterest' in 'where clause'
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong, what I need to do to correct this?

Comment: What do you get if you print `$query`? Also be sure to clean any variable you enter into a query, a malicious user could inject sql.

Comment: Thank you, but this is just testing code and I'm sick to death of people trolling posts looking to tell them all about sql injection attacks and to give me a negative number on my post...

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, nor do I trawl questions looking for sql injection vulnerabilities. I only added this as I was already asking a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest echoing out your query, it'll help with debugging.  Your query currently looks like:

```
SELECT MemberID FROM MemberInterests WHERE Interest IN (WhateverInterest,Testing)
```

As you can see, in the `IN` the values are unquoted, so they're interpreted as field names.  You need to add quotes around each value in the `IN`.

You can fix it by looping, and adding quotes around each value:

```
foreach($_POST['Interest'] as &$intrest){
    $intrest = "'$intrest'";
}
$InterestMatches = implode(',', $_POST['Interest']);
```

Or by imploding with `"','"`, and then adding quotes before and after:

```
$InterestMatches = "'" . implode("','", $_POST['Interest']) . "'";
```

P.S. You should `mysql_real_escape_string` each value in `$_POST['Interest']` to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: I used your code, thank you, it made it work... The only problem now is that the query result gives me all results that have any of the interests... For instance, if I search for 2 different interests, it will give me all results regardless of whether or not they have ALL of the interests... You know what I mean?

Comment: @MichaelConklin: That's how `IN` works.  `IN` is the same as having multiple `OR` statements.

Comment: @MichaelConklin: You could use PHP to filter the rows to only the ones that contain *all* the interests.  There's gotta be a way to do it in MySQL, but I can't think of it.  Why don't you ask another question about that? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$InterestMatches = '"' . implode('","', $_POST['Interest']) . '"';
```

Comment: Sorry, LOL, your post was so small that I didn't even see it, but it looks just like the one that I used from the other responder that worked...